# Need help in SQL query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have two tables as follows:

Table A

```
-------------------------------------
TotalClicks  Market__c  JourneyName
7             Tampa       J1
4             Dallas      J1
21            Tampa       J2
3             Dallas      J2
-------------------------------------
```

Table B

```
-------------------------------------
UniqueClicks   Market__c  JourneyName
2              Tampa        J1
4              Dallas       J1
5              Tampa        J2
8              Dallas       J2
-------------------------------------
```

I have the third table which should have the combined output of the above two tables.

Table C

```
--------------------------------------
TotalClicks         UniqueClicks         Market__c        JourneyName__c
7                      2                   Tampa              J1
4                      4                   Dallas             J1
21                     5                   Tampa              J2
3                      8                    Dallas            J2
```

I have tried the following query but it is not giving me the desired result

```
Select  A.TotalClicks,B.UniqueClicks,A.Market__c, A.JourneyName from JourneyReport_TotalClicks A JOIN JourneyReport_UniqueClicks B
on A.Market__c = A.Market__c
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the JourneyName in the join?

```
Select  A.TotalClicks,B.UniqueClicks,A.Market__c, A.JourneyName
from JourneyReport_TotalClicks A
JOIN JourneyReport_UniqueClicks B
    on A.Market__c = A.Market__c and A.JourneyName = B.JourneyName
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is giving me the desired output.